# Manage Multiple Audio Sources in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I have a React component that plays/pauses audio when you click on a button. It works great and I render about 5 of these on a page at once. However, if you click play on one, and then click play on another, both audio's are playing, which isn't great. Here's my code for the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import playIcon from './images/play.png';
import pauseIcon from './images/pause.png';
class Music extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 'play': false };
        this.url = props.src;
        this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
        this.audio.preload = 'none';
        this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
    }

    togglePlay() {
        this.setState({'play': !this.state.play}, () => {
            this.state.play ? this.audio.play() : this.audio.pause();
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        this.audio.pause();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.props.style} className={this.props.className}>
                {this.state.play
                    ? <button className="audio-button" aria-label="Pause" onClick={this.togglePlay}><img src={pauseIcon} width="34" height="34" alt="Pause"></img></button>
                    : <button className="audio-button" aria-label="Play" onClick={this.togglePlay}><img src={playIcon} width="34" height="34" alt="Play"></img></button>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Music;
```

I've done some looking around and a potential solution is to use redux or some other state management library. I'd like to avoid this as I otherwise have no need for that in this site. I've looked into event listeners (namely the [solution proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790506/multiple-audio-html-auto-stop-other-when-current-is-playing-with-javascript)) but when I do a `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')` I get back an empty `HTMLCollection`. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747383/how-to-pause-all-playing-audios-on-a-page) is closer, but I can't bridge the gap between it's implementation in jQuery to the one I'm using in React.

Is there a way to identify the playing audio and pause it from a React Component before playing new audio? Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't the audio a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got some big hints from Xuezheng Ma and TheIncorrigible1. Basically moved audio into it's own module. `play` and `pause` methods are exported from that, and `currentlyPlaying` is tracked in that module.

I adjusted my `Music` component to look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import playIcon from './images/play.png';
import pauseIcon from './images/pause.png';
import globalAudio from './globalAudio';

class Music extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 'play': false };
        this.name = props.src;
        this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
    }

    togglePlay() {
        this.setState({'play': !this.state.play}, () => {
            this.state.play ? globalAudio.play(this.name) : globalAudio.pause(this.name);
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        globalAudio.pause(this.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.props.style} className={this.props.className}>
                {this.state.play
                    ? <button className="audio-button" aria-label="Pause" onClick={this.togglePlay}><img src={pauseIcon} width="34" height="34" alt="Pause"></img></button>
                    : <button className="audio-button" aria-label="Play" onClick={this.togglePlay}><img src={playIcon} width="34" height="34" alt="Play"></img></button>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Music;
```

And my new module `globalAudio`:

```
import audio1 from './audio1.mp3';
import audio2 from './audio2.mp3';
import audio3 from './audio3.mp3';
import audio4 from './audio4.mp3';
import audio5 from './audio5.mp3';

const audios = {
    'audio1': new Audio(audio1),
    'audio2': new Audio(audio2),
    'audio3': new Audio(audio3),
    'audio4': new Audio(audio4),
    'audio5': new Audio(audio5)
};

let currentlyPlaying = null;

const play = (name) => {
    if (currentlyPlaying) {
        audios[currentlyPlaying].pause();
    }
    audios[name].play();
    currentlyPlaying = name;
};

const pause = (name) => {
    currentlyPlaying = null;
    audios[name].pause();
};

export default {
    pause,
    play
};
```

Thanks for all of the suggestions, they were all very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';

import audio1 from './audio1.mp3';
import audio2 from './audio2.mp3';

class AudioList extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.audios = props.list.map(audio => new Audio(audio));
    }

    getCurrentAudio () {
        return this.audios.find(audio => false === audio.paused);
    }

    toggle (nextAudio) {
        const currentAudio = this.getCurrentAudio();

        if (currentAudio && currentAudio !== nextAudio) {
            currentAudio.pause();
        }

        nextAudio.paused ? nextAudio.play() : nextAudio.pause();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.audios.map((audio, index) =>
                    <button onClick={() => this.toggle(audio) }>
                        PLAY AUDIO { index }
                    </button>
                ) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default () => <AudioList list={[ audio1, audio2 ]} />;
```

PS: `new Audio(url)` returns a **HTMLAudioElement**.

Comment: I like this idea, but this returns a list of audio buttons instead of just one. And I think you're right about `new Audio(url)` returning an HTMLAudioElement, but if I do a `document.getElementByTag('audio')` with a few of these mounted, I get back an empty array. I've edited my question to say this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module to handle audio. Expose methods like play, pause, resume, etc, to `Music`, and keep track of different audios from all five `Music` instance you have. Whenever a new audio is played, paused the old one.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what this implementation would look like?